# Correct way to use SELECT INTO with WebSQL and HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

```
speeddial.storage.Sync = function() {
  chrome.bookmarks.getChildren(String(localStorage['rootFolderID']), function(newSync){
    speeddial.storage.db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM bookmarksSync',null,null,speeddial.storage.onError);   
      tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM groupsSync',null,null,speeddial.storage.onError);  
      for (var i=0; i<newSync.length; i++){
    if(!newSync[i].url)
    {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT INTO groupsSync FROM groups', [],null
      ,speeddial.storage.onError);
    }
    ...
    //above is the end of else statement
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I want to use SELECT * INTO to copy some values from one SQL table to another. When I use the above
  I get near INTO syntax error. 
I WANT TO NOW HOW TO DO BOTH THINGS - copy the values of some columns form table A to table B based on a specific column value, and completely replacing the contend of table A with this of table B
Thank you ;)

Comment: Web SQL Database: ["Beware. This specification is no longer in active maintenance and the Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further."](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

Comment: Thank you. But I actually try to mod an existing app not written by me, so I have to re-write the whole code over. I am aware of this

Comment: I dont known about WebSQL, but maybe next SQL command is more proper: _'SELECT * FROM groups INTO groupsSync'_ ?

Comment: Or turn around the whole thing: `INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2) SELECT column1, column2 FROM old_tablename;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`INSERT INTO groupsSync SELECT * FROM groups`

For more information on websql queries look into sqlite [INSERT INTO syntax documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)